# Foreach loop with multidimensional arrays in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I am getting an error while compiling the following cpp code:

```cpp
int x[][2]{{1, 2}, {3, 4}};

for (int e[2] : x) {
    std::cout << e[0] << ' ' << e[1] << '\n';
}
```

This gives the following error:

`error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer`

I did replaced `int e[2]` with `auto e` and that worked but I want to work with the actual type.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: This would be easier with `std::array`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the correct fixed-size declaration is

```cpp
for (int(&e)[2] : x) {}
```

or you can use `auto&` to deduce it

```cpp
for (auto& e : x) {} // same as above
```

---

note: `auto` doesn't deduce the same type

```cpp
for (auto e : x) {} // e is int*
```

Comment: fwiw https://godbolt.org/z/4shcEvvaa

Comment: It works but it seems like we are using a reference type like a reference(`int(&e)[2]`) or pointer (`int *`). Though I know that C-style arrays are actually pointers internally. Can't we just use an actual array type like we do in a one dimensional array? Thank you.

Comment: @AK-CHP then you'd copy the content, which probably is not what you want. (and yes, you cannot copy raw array type)

Comment: I am just hacking. Surely I won't do it in an actual program. I just want to explore whether it can be done :).

Comment: @AK-CHP no, you cannot copy raw array that way, in range-based-for or not.

Comment: @AK-CHP details are here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for. Its just a bit complicated to read because documentation has to account for 3 different cases

Answer (score 2):

interpret the inner array as a pointer:

```
#include <iostream>
   
int main() {
    int x[][2]{{1, 2}, {3, 4}};

    for (int* e : x) {
        std::cout << e[0] << ' ' << e[1] << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Surely working, but there's no need to decay the array into a pointer here. `auto&` would be the better option. +1 nevertheless since it's actually a working solution.

Comment: you loose the information of the size  of the array. With the pointer you cannot eg use range based loop on the inner array like this https://godbolt.org/z/e4vE4vcdo